# PHP 7.4.21 Strange Behaviour inside Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I'm puzzled by the behaviour of PHP 7.4.21. Inside a Wordpress page I have this piece of code:

```
<span class="team-member-social">
    <?php 
        if(the_field('facebook_link')) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('facebook_link'); ?>"><i class="<?php the_field('facebook_icon'); ?>"></i></a>
    <?php }
        if(the_field('github_link')) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('github_link'); ?>"><i class="<?php the_field('github_icon'); ?>"></i></a>
    <?php }
        if(the_field('dribble_link')) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('dribble_link'); ?>"><i class="<?php the_field('dribble_icon'); ?>"></i></a>
    <?php   }
        if(the_field('tumblr_link')) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('tumblr_link'); ?>"><i class="<?php the_field('tumblr_icon'); ?>"></i></a>
    <?php   } ?>
</span>
```

the function the_field() is a function of ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) plugin and returns a string with the content the user has set inside the custom field.

The strange behviour I'm referring to is that inside the ifs all the blocks of HTML code (`<a...><i...></i></a>`) is returned like a simple text containing the value of `<?php the_field('XXX_link'); ?>` and not in the correct format (a series of social network icons).

When I remove the ifs the pieces of code are shown correctly.

Any suggestion on how this may occur?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`the_field()` echos the data, you have to use `get_field()` in the if statement

From the ACF docs [here](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/the_field/)

> Please note this function is the same as echo get_field().

like this

```
<span class="team-member-social">
    <?php 
        if(get_field('facebook_link')) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('facebook_link'); ?>"><i class="<?php the_field('facebook_icon'); ?>"></i></a>
    <?php }
        if(get_field('github_link')) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('github_link'); ?>"><i class="<?php the_field('github_icon'); ?>"></i></a>
    <?php }
        if(get_field('dribble_link')) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('dribble_link'); ?>"><i class="<?php the_field('dribble_icon'); ?>"></i></a>
    <?php   }
        if(get_field('tumblr_link')) { ?>
            <a href="<?php the_field('tumblr_link'); ?>"><i class="<?php the_field('tumblr_icon'); ?>"></i></a>
    <?php   } ?>
</span>
```